# How do I connect to SQLite db file from c#?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, ado.net, connection-string

I am trying to connect to a sqllite db from with a c# application. I have never worked with SQLLite before.

```
var connectionString = @"data source='C:\TestData\StressData.s3db'";
            connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
```

When i attempt to open the connection I get the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks..

Nick

Update:

I changed 'data source' to 'DataSource' as suggested to me. Now I receive a new error:

After changing this I get a new error: System.ArgumentException: Data Source cannot be empty. Use :memory: to open an in-memory database at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()

Any more suggestions?

Comment: Try removing the apostrophes within your connection string DataSource parameter: `@"DataSource=c:\TestData\StressData.s3db"`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got it..

```
"data source=c:\TestData\StressData.s3db; Version=3;"
```

Looks like the 'Version' attribute is not optional. Interesting that the .NET provider does not show this in the designer property window.

Comment: Using SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder object to build a connection string (instead of hardcoding it as a string) elliminates most of the problems like this (ambiguous parameter names, typos). When it comes to Version attribute, at least my SQLite doesn't need it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.html), `data source` should be `DataSource`

Comment: Doh! I think you are right. After changing this I get a new error:


System.ArgumentException: Data Source cannot be empty.  Use :memory: to open an in-memory database
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()

I must have to provide an argument?

Comment: @Nick, I've never used this, but from the docs it sounds like the argument should be `new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=C:\TestData\StressData.s3db")`. I don't know why it's not working :\

Comment: Actually it looks like it should 'data source'